# Query as a conditional statement in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-1.9.3

Was following the Depot application from Agile Web Development with Rails.
There was a method I got confused. I thought I understood it until I tried it in irb. So here's the method:

```
  def add_product(product_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product_id)
    end

    current_item
  end
```

From what I understood, It's just a method that will first find a record in LineItems with a product ID of an give input (let's say it's 10). Then it will store it in current_item variable. The condition says 'If the product id was found, add 1 to quantity else create a new instance of that record with the product id equals to 10'

Here's the snapshot of my rails console

[image]

As you can see, product id of 10 in LineItem is not found. But on my condition, it goes against everything that I believe until now. Could someone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `line` is an empty collection (ActiveRecord::Relation to be exact) and so it's something in Ruby and not nil. That's why it's returning true when you're calling `if line` and executing `puts 'I'm true and happy'`.The reason it's an ActiveRecord::Relation is because you're using the *where* query.

In the Depot application they're making the query by calling `line_items.find_by_product_id(product_id)` which is different. It finds the first record matching the condition.

Check out the Rails guides here for more info -  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html (section 15)

PS Looks like that type of query is deprecated in Rails 4 so not sure what version of Agile Web Development with Rails you're looking at.